# Typescript visual studio 2015 es5

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, ecmascript-6

We are using visual studio 2015, and have the following typescript :-

```
class Form extends TestBase {
constructor(obj, settings) {
super();
super.automap(this, obj, Object.assign({}, settings, { overrides: { Template: Template } }));
  }
}
```

Using the visual studio 2015 typescript compiler,  this compils down to :-

```
class Form extends TestBase {
constructor(obj, settings) {
    super();
    super.automap(this, obj, Object.assign({}, settings, { overrides: {} }));
}
}
```

Which is fine, and works great in chrome,  however,  we would like this to also work in ie10 / ie11.

i believe that we need to 'polyfill' this so that the js file generated is converted to es5.

Is there currently anything in visual studio that can do this? What is the best way for this conversion? or any samples?

Comment: Did you try setting your `target` property in `tsconfig.json` to `es3`?

Comment: @Saravana we do not use the tsconfig.json as this disables the TypeScript Build  which are available in the properties for the web app.

Answer (score 0):

From TypeScript 2.1 you can use spread syntax:

```
super.automap(this, obj, { ...settings, overrides: { Template: Template } } );
```

This will transpile into `Object.assign`, including polyfill.

Comment: I dont think this would work as we have lots of es6 syntax. Trying to use babel, however, this doesnt seem to be having any effect on the script that is being generated, and we cannot find any working examples.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You can [check it out yourself](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20settings%20%3D%20%7B%20Item1%3A%20%22Item1%22%2C%20Item2%3A%20%22Item2%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20merged%20%3D%20%7B%20...settings%2C%20overrides%3A%20%7B%20Template%3A%20%22Template%22%20%7D%20%7D%20)